# Get test title and state in selenium-webdriver.js testing

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I am writing mocha tests with [selenium-webdriver.js](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/index.html), and trying to take screenshot only if the current test failed.

In Mocha, I can get the current test info like title and state as follows:

```
afterEach(function(){
  console.log('afterEach', this.currentTest.title, this.currentTest.state);
});
```

But selenium-webdriver.js wraps around Mocha's interface with selenium-webdriver/testing, and the original this.currentTest is not exposed anymore:

```
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
test.afterEach(function(){
  //console.log('afterEach', this.currentTest.title, this.currentTest.state);
});
```

I am wondering if such information is still exposed somehow or is there any workaround for this.

Comment: Is this still not working for you? I'm able to filter on this.currentTest.state perfectly fine, this might've been implemented after you asked the question, perhaps?

Comment: Does anyone has a solution for this with the new Selenium 4? I am trying to get it but a `console.log(this)` in the test (in `beforeEach` or in `it` block) prints `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

```
this.title - returns suite name
this.ctx.currentTest.title - returns current test name
this.ctx.currentTest.state - returns current test state
```

Doesn't work if used arrow function for "describe".

Comment: In the actual test spec you can access by `this.test`, while anything in `describe` or `beforeEach` you will need to use `currentTest`. Also make sure not use arrow functions as that will rewrite the `this` context.